# Scheme and Build Pre-Action Script Output?

Tags: xcode, build

I have a scheme in Xcode 4. I edited the scheme so that *Build* has a *Pre-Action*, and that action is a *script*.

The script is simple - it dumps pre-processor defines: `cpp -dM < /dev/null`.

Where do I find the output of the script?

Answer (score 10):

add this line to pre-action script

```
pwd > ~/current_directory.txt
```

then check file current_directory.txt in your home directory

Comment: That just takes me to a directory that is chock-full of who-knows-what: `/private/var/folders/_p/mp_84lr50bxc8957ch30wknh0000gn/T`. Still can't find the output. :(

Comment: Just tested again, that **chock-full of who-knows-what** directory contains my newly created file. Care to elaborate on what you are trying to achieve and your steps ?

Comment: Is there a specific naming convention that the output file matches? I wasn't able to identify the file among the 661 files and folders in that directory. This folder appears to be the dumping grounds for all the programs on the computer. Using sublime, I did a file-content search in that directory, and it didn't return any of my echo statements. I'm attempting to get the output for this [script](https://pontifex.azurewebsites.net/xcode-auto-increment-build-on-archive/).

Comment: Just did an `echo ${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE} > ~/Debug.txt` and `~/Debug.txt` contains path to .plist file.